# trigger Button onClick on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I am setting up ViewPager on my `onCreate()` but when I try to set click listener one of the layout tab button, it does not respond. Here is how my `onCreate()` is set up.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.join_login);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new JoinLoginAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    // Set up the login form.
    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login_tab, null);

    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.login_password);

    //mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login_password || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}
```

My `JoinLoginAdapter` extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I have three layouts, one is the ContentView whereas the other two are the two tabs for my `ViewPager`. The problem is `mPasswordView` and other buttons currently in the two tabs do not respond on click. I also have the adapter below for my ViewPager.

```
public class JoinLoginAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public JoinLoginAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        LoginFragment logintab = new LoginFragment();
        return logintab;
    }
    else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        JoinFragment jointab = new JoinFragment();
        return jointab;
    }

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
}
```

I have been thinking the ViewPager is interfering with the clicks but I cannot seem to find how to solve this. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is mPasswordView and other buttons currently in the two
>   tabs do not respond on click. I have been thinking the ViewPager is
>   interfering with the clicks but I cannot seem to find how to solve
>   this. What exactly am I doing wrong?

you are using a `inflater`, to get a reference a reference to view handled by the fragments in your `ViewPager`. You are doing the wrong assumption that the  `inflater` is returning you the same view's reference that the Fragments handled by the ViewPager are inflating. What is returning the inflater in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` is different from what you are seeing at screen. You should let the `Fragment`s handle their `OnClicKListener`

Comment: Can you please explain with a short piece of code. Do you mean I should find button like this `mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);` because when doing this, the Button is null.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Could you post your adpter ?

Comment: all the Logic you are handling in the Activity goes to your LoginFragment.